# Why am I unable to run UFW?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, firewall, firewalld, ufw

[image]

A few weeks ago, out of curiosity, I disabled `ufw` and started using `firewalld`.

I want to start using `ufw` again, but as you can see in the screenshot, `systemctl status ufw` outputs **"active (exited)"** instead of **"active (running)**.**"**

What do I do now? Please help!!! :(

> **Distro:** Linux Mint 19.3
> **DE:** Cinnamon 4.4.8

Comment: AFAIK `active (exited)` is normal for services of type `oneshot` - see for example [status ufw problem (exited)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117921/status-ufw-problem-exited)

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the **relevant** text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: Thanks, cas, for sharing the "Please don't post images of text" link. I never thought of this. I'll keep this in mind while asking for help again. :)